# sqoop inserting data into wrong hive column from rdbms table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a table called 'employee' in SQL Server :

```
ID  NAME    ADDRESS   DESIGNATION
1   Jack     XXX       Clerk
2   John     YYY       Engineer
```

I have created an external table (emp) in hive and through sqoop import I imported data from employee to hive table using --query argument of sqoop. If I mention --query as '`select * from employee`' then data gets inserted to hive table correctly.But if I mention --query as '`select ID,NAME,DESIGNATION`' from employee' then data in DESIGNATION column of 'employee' table(rdbms) is getting inserted to address column of 'emp' table instead of getting inserted to designation column.When I run the below hive query:

```
select designation from emp;
```

I get values as :
NULL
NULL 
instead of : Clerk
             Engineer
But if I run the hive query as :

```
select address from emp;
```

I get values as :
Clerk
Engineer
instead of :NULL
            NULL
Any ideas of fixing this incorrect data would be of great help.I am currently using 0.11 version of hive so I can't use hive insert queries which are available from 0.14 hive version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,I show you a sample.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://host:port/db'?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8' \
--username 'xxxx' \
--password 'xxxx' \
--table employee \
--columns 'ID,NAME,DESIGNATION' \
--where 'aaa=bbb' \
-m 1 \
--target-dir hdfs://nameservice1/dir \
--fields-terminated-by '\t' \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
--null-string '\\N' \
--hive-table 'hive_db.hive_tb' \
--hive-partition-key 'pt' \
--hive-partition-value '2016-01-20'
```

and some param is optional.

sqoop syntax detail:
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal

Answer (score 0):

The Sqoop statement will import the data to hdfs directory as(assuming field separator as ,)

```
1,Jack,Clerk
2,John,Engineer
```

So Address column will have DESIGNATION data and DESIGNATION column will be null

You can try --query "select ID,NAME,'',DESIGNATION from employee", this should work

Comment: This approach provides a temporary solution but our requirement is such that we shouldn't force the users to write the query in that way.

Comment: Sorry but dont understand your requirement, The hdfs external location fields will be mapped to the hive table structure so you have to sqoop import specific columns accordingly, Using --query as 'select ID,NAME,DESIGNATION' which are mapped to the hive table columns ID ,NAME ,ADDRESS , DESIGNATION will give you DESIGNATION  null only, you have to change hive table structure or query